# filter rows that have X number of columns with value greater than Y

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to filter my data frame to keep only rows that have values > 5.5 in at least 2 columns.

I know the `dplyr` function `filter(df,columnX>5.5)`, but it only allows to take one or a few columns at a time.

df:

```
    structure(list(tumor = c(5.69857588735462, 5.14269655336569, 
15.5965461799242, 5.28949625542, 6.43237599127586, 5.21673785968077
), tumor = c(5.79729396999926, 5.10961482429376, 15.8339301491681, 
5.47321124082556, 6.0624492087845, 5.21740033243091), tumor = c(5.67184459054712, 
5.024088977993, 16.1659194908984, 5.20119456848026, 6.67441109230211, 
5.15023836750153), tumor = c(5.9616857066853, 5.23907758025991, 
15.2742729676712, 5.31827944648937, 6.47526325782951, 5.15926657492595
), tumor = c(5.75116456249489, 5.03195808382708, 16.0180448251626, 
5.36575242301428, 6.85603803194346, 5.18022831262029)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A_33_P3390097", 
"NM_178466", "GE_BrightCorner", "ENST00000396843", "NM_001166137", 
"DarkCorner"))
```

Comment: Quick question. Is the above code giving you a data frame?

Comment: try know. edited

Comment: Still doesn't look like a data frame. `dplyr` will not understand this object afaik.

Comment: Okay I just spotted thue `class` argument somewhere in the jungle. Next time, do format your code a bit :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple and quick way using base R `rowSums`, where we filter those rows which has value greater than 5.5 in more than one column.

```
df[rowSums(df > 5.5) > 1, ]

#                    tumor     tumor     tumor     tumor     tumor
#A_33_P3390097    5.698576  5.797294  5.671845  5.961686  5.751165
#GE_BrightCorner 15.596546 15.833930 16.165919 15.274273 16.018045
#NM_001166137     6.432376  6.062449  6.674411  6.475263  6.856038
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using @Ronak `rowSums` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(rowSums(.[1:5]>5.5)>=2)
```

PS: Before using this solution with OP dataset, change column names using `colnames(df)<- paste0('X',1:5)`, to avoid the following error:

> Error: Columns `tumor`, `tumor`, `tumor`, `tumor` must have unique names